# Exporting to PNG from Adobe Illustrator cutting off edges

Tags: png, adobe-illustrator

I created a 40px x 40px image in Adobe Illustrator CS4. I saved as an .ai file and then tried to export as a PNG.

Adobe Illustrator automatically crops the background and tightens the export to a rect around all the objects which if fine. In this case, I am not working edge to edge so my image is not quite 40px wide.

But, unfortunately, Illustrator is not exporting the entire image. I end up with an image that is 34px wide. Indeed, the icon I draw starts on the left hand side but the right edge of my object cut off.

Any ideas why this is happening? I can't imagine Illustrator CS4 can't correctly to export to PNG.

Comment: More appropriate for http://superuser.com/.

Comment: @DannyVarod: [Don't tag not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**File/Export** option gives you much more options. When the Export dialog box apears, under the save type as PNG, you have **"Use Artboards"** radio button. Tick that and PNG will be saved as a whole page instead of automatic croping. A plus is that you'll have a second dialog box where you can set the PNG's resolution.

Answer (score 6):

In CS5 I have found the opposite to be true. I tried the File>Export option and it kept expanding my image to include white space around it. Once I used File>Save for Web & Devices it worked perfectly. The "save as type" was able to be set to "Images Only (*.png)"

Answer (score 1):

Are you exporting the image by going to File>Export or are you using File>Save For Web & Devices. I think this problem only appears when you are trying the latter. Usually File>Export gives you good result.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues... even on clicking the radio button of art board,Its dint work for me, later i figured out that i dint make any background for my file. I added a layer of background and it worked exactly the way i want.

Comment: What if one wanted a transparent background?